# How can i get selected option value in thymleaf

Tags: jsp, thymeleaf

Hello guys i'm new in thymleaf i want to use select options :

```
    <div>
        <div class="form-group blu-margin">
            <select class="form-control" id="idville" name="idville">
                <option value="0" disabled selected>Select Ville : </option>
                <option th:each="v : ${villes}" th:value="${v.id}" th:text="${v.name}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <a th:href="@{projections(vp=${idville} )}" th:text="Chercher" style="color:black"></a>
    </div>
```

And i have problem in href of the link it pass anything a i want to get selected value from select
Can someone help me to solve the problem
Cause i get empty parameter : 
http://localhost:9090/projections?vp=
Thanks in advance

Comment: i don't know much about thymeleaf but you can do this using `jquery` or `js` .

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you want to update the `href` attribute of the `a` link depending on the selection in the `<select>`? If so, that is not possible with Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf renders the HTML page one time, there are no dynamic updates happening on the client side. You will need to use plain Javascript or maybe a minimal library like [AlpineJS](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine)